# Yii2 validation on controller action

Tags: validation, yii2

I am developing a Yii 2.0 application in which users can create orders then send the orders to review and after that it follows a number of stages in the workflow.

Everything is ok until yesterday that the customer ask for the possibility that before sending the orders to review the order are considered as draft. Which means I have to turn off validations on create and validate them when users clicks Send To Review button.  I know Yii 2.0 supports scenarios but maybe scenarios doesn't apply to this because the Send To Review button is shown in a readonly view.  This forces me to do validation inside the controller action because there is no send_to_review view.  How can this be done (I mean model validation inside controller action)?

Here is the controller action code

```
public function actionSendToReview($id)
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('Salesperson'))
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($model->orden_stage_id == 1 && $model->sales_person_id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id)
        {
            $model->orden_stage_id = 2;
            $model->date_modified = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
            $model->modified_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;

            //TODO: Validation logic if is not valid show validation errors
            //for example "For sending to review this values are required:
            //list of attributes in bullets"
            //A preferred way would be to auto redirect to update action but 
            //showing the validation error and setting scenario to              
            //"send_to_review".


            $model->save();
            $this::insertStageHistory($model->order_id, 2);
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException();
    }
}
```

What I need to solve is the TODO. 
Option 1: Showing validation errors in the same view and the user has to clic Update button change the requested values save and then try to Send To Review again.
Option 2: Redirecting automatically to update view already setting scenario and validation errors found in the controller.

Thanks,

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$model ->validate()`for validation in controller.

```
public function actionSendToReview($id)
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('Salesperson'))
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($model->orden_stage_id == 1 && $model->sales_person_id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id)
        {
            $model->orden_stage_id = 2;
            $model->date_modified = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
            $model->modified_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;



            //TODO: Validation logic if is not valid show validation errors
            //for example "For sending to review this values are required:
            //list of attributes in bullets"
            //A preferred way would be to auto redirect to update action but 
            //showing the validation error and setting scenario to              
            //"send_to_review".

            //optional
            $model->scenario=//put here the scenario for validation;

             //if everything is validated as per scenario
             if($model ->validate())
            {                   
               $model->save();
               $this::insertStageHistory($model->order_id, 2);
               return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->render('update', [
                 'model' => $model,
               ]);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException();
    }
}
```

If you don't need validation in `actionCreate()`.Create a scenario for not validating any field and apply there.

Comment: It works fine but now validation errors are shown twice. Weird